# can you create a ts definition that checks for ANY typescript interface?

Tags: typescript

i have an interface, where i want to enforce an interface is defined in my definition, but allow *any* interface to be used. something like...

```js
interface Foo {
  enabled: boolean
}

interface Settings {
  [key: string]: AnyInterface

  // will pass
  foo: IFoo;

  // will fail
  bar: {
    key: string;
  }
}
```

i want to avoid `[key: string]: IFoo | IBar | ...`. is this possible? or perhaps a better solution altogether?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the question correctly, but what's wrong with the `any` type for what you're looking for?

Comment: Typescript uses structural typing to determine if an object implements an interface, so in your example, `bar` *does* implement the `Foo` interface.

Comment: @Netero i updated the description.. i want to enforce that an interface is defined, but to allow it to be any interface

Comment: @IanMcLaird it's a bit of a contrived example... i can update the example to be more clear

Comment: `{key: string}` is also an interface. There is no relevant difference between an interface declared like `interface Bar {key: string}` and `type Bar = {key: string}`.

Comment: I think you're looking for: `[key: string]: { enabled: boolean }`